# Spring Cloud Gateway modifyResponseBody of Flux

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I am having some trouble to modify a Flux response in Spring Cloud Gateway. My setup (simplified) is as follows:
I have 2 domain objects:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PersonV10 {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PersonV20 {
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

Now my service is returning instances of PersonV20 and using Spring Cloud Gateway I would like to modify the response to become a PersonV10. On /person I get a Flux<Person> as response and on /person/{id} I get a Mono<Person> as response.

My route is as follows:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("rewrite_response_v20", r -> r.path("/person/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.modifyResponseBody(PersonV20.class, PersonV10.class,
                            (exchange, p) -> Mono.just(new PersonV10(p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getLastName()))))
                    .uri("https://localhost:8444"))
                    .build();
}
```

When calling the /person/{id} endpoint this works perfectly and my response gets modified to a PersonV10 nicely. However, when I now call the /person endpoint I am getting back a Flux and I get this exception in Spring Cloud Gateway:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.gateway.mutate_response_filter.PersonV20` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.example.gateway.mutate_response_filter.PersonV20` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:215) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Now I guess this makes sense since I am getting a Flux as response and in modifyResponseBody I am using a Mono. But how to use a Flux in this situation is not clear to me. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

from spring cloud gateway source code, you will find a TODO which says 'TODO: flux or mono'. that means resently only mono type supported.

```
// TODO: flux or mono
Mono modifiedBody = extractBody(exchange, clientResponse, inClass)
                    .flatMap(originalBody -> config.getRewriteFunction().apply(exchange,
                            originalBody))
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> (Mono) config.getRewriteFunction()
                            .apply(exchange, null)));
```

if you want use default ModifyResponseBodyFilter, maybe you could put class in a wrapper class, e.g.

```
class PersonV2ListWrapper{
    public List<PersonV2> persons;
}
```

otherwise, a self filter to implement ModifyResponseBodyFilter's function and support Flux, may also helpful.

Comment: Thanks! The wrapper suggestion was very useful. It did not work out of the box but you did put me on the right track. It turns out that if I make the types an array of Person objects then it actually works! I'll post a more complete answer of my solution in a separate answer.

Comment: Hoping for your new post. seems like i misunderstand that part of source code. i will also try this as your mentioned.

Comment: I have posted the working code. Very much interested in your perspective why the path is not being selected correctly without the extra predicate.

Comment: to @JonckvanderKogel, you may test two method:  r -> r.path(ROOT_PATTERN).order(a big value). or. r -> r.path(ROOT_PATTERN, false)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint of @eric I was able to get this working. A few caveats: by now wrapping the collection in a Mono of course I am now removing some of the benefits of the reactive stream so a better approach will of course be to write an implementation of ModifyResponseBodyFilter that supports Flux. Another item is slightly off topic for the original question so I'll cover that at the end of this post.

The solution which ended up working for me:

```
private static final String ROOT_PATTERN = "/person";
private static final String INDIVIDUAL_PATTERN = "/person/*";
private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("rewrite_response_v20_flux", r -> r.path(ROOT_PATTERN)
                    .filters(f -> f.modifyResponseBody(PersonV20[].class, PersonV10[].class,
                            (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(
                                    Stream.of(s)
                                            .map(v20 -> new PersonV10(v20.getId(), v20.getFirstName() + " " + v20.getLastName()))
                                            .toArray(PersonV10[]::new)
                            )))
                    .uri("https://localhost:8444")
                    .predicate(e -> pathMatcher.match(ROOT_PATTERN, e.getRequest().getPath().value()))
            )
            .route("rewrite_response_v20_mono", r -> r.path(INDIVIDUAL_PATTERN)
                    .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/person/(?<ID>.*)", "/person/${ID}")
                            .modifyResponseBody(PersonV20.class, PersonV10.class,
                                    (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(new PersonV10(s.getId(), s.getFirstName() + " " + s.getLastName()))))
                    .uri("https://localhost:8444")
                    .predicate(e -> pathMatcher.match(INDIVIDUAL_PATTERN, e.getRequest().getPath().value()))
            )
            .build();
}
```

Now to get back to the caveat I mentioned above: what struck me as odd is that currently the two path patterns are not sufficient to distinguish between the two different endpoints. I have written a test that demonstrates that the AntPathMatcher (which is used under the hood if you check the JavaDoc) is able to distinguish between /person and /person/1 with the patterns that I provide. Here are the tests:

```
public class PathMatcherTests {
    private AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    private static final String ROOT_ENDPOINT = "/person";
    private static final String INDIVIDUAL_ENDPOINT = "/person/1";

    @Test
    public void shouldMatchRootButNotIndividual() {
        String rootMatchPattern = "/person";

        assertTrue(pathMatcher.match(rootMatchPattern, ROOT_ENDPOINT));
        assertFalse(pathMatcher.match(rootMatchPattern, INDIVIDUAL_ENDPOINT));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldMatchIndividualButNotRoot() {
        String individualMatchPattern = "/person/*";

        assertFalse(pathMatcher.match(individualMatchPattern, ROOT_ENDPOINT));
        assertTrue(pathMatcher.match(individualMatchPattern, INDIVIDUAL_ENDPOINT));
    }
}
```

But even though this test succeeds if I do not add the extra predicate at the end testing the request path it does not work for me. If I put the rewrite_response_v20_flux route first the individual person requests fail with a DecodingException like in my original post and if I put the rewrite_response_v20_mono route first then the full listing of person request fails. In my opinion the extra predicate should not be necessary but nevertheless to get it working I had to add those.

Any additional comments/help on this topic is most welcome since even though this "works" the solution is still not yet ideal.

Hope this helps someone at least.